# ios: Replace word in NSString with a return

Tags: ios, replace, nsstring

I have the following NSString:

```
"This is a test String
*This a test string"
```

I want to replace the "*" with  a return like so

```
"This is a test string

This is a test string"
```

I tried:

```
[removeStr stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"*" withString:@"/r"];
```

but it prints "/r" and when I try "\r" I get an lldb error

Any help?

Comment: yup that was it. I had tried /n but needed \n ahhh! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSString *str = @"This is a test String*This a test string";
NSString *str2 = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"*" withString:@"\n"];
NSLog(@"%@", str2);
```

If the string like that, replace `\n`, then the result is:

```
This is a test String
This a test string
```